# Como mudar a cor da linha de um DBGrid no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Estou fazendo um sistema de controle de gastos, e ao registrar uma nova receita ou nova despesa quero que mude a cor da linha desse registro no `dbGrid` conforme escolhido, usei um `TDBRadioGroup` para escolher entre **'Despesa'** e **'Receita'**. Como ficaria o código?

Comment: seria uma cor pra despesa e outra pra receita?

Comment: Sim, como resolvi gravar as despesas e receitas na mesma tabela, quero que diferencie no dbGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu banco de dados deve ter um campo onde informa se o valor é uma despesa ou receita. Digamos que o nome desse campo se chame *'tipo'*. Você poderá alterar as cores assim:

Dois cliques no evento **onDrawColumnCell** do seu *DBGrid*

```
    If tabelaTIPO.Value = 'despesa' then // condição
      begin
      Dbgrid1.Canvas.Font.Color:= clRed; // coloque aqui a cor desejada
      Dbgrid1.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, dbgrid1.columns[datacol].field, State);
      end else
      begin
      Dbgrid1.Canvas.Font.Color:= clGreen; // coloque aqui a cor desejada
      Dbgrid1.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, dbgrid1.columns[datacol].field, State);
      end;
```

O que o código faz é verificar se no campo TIPO de sua tabela esteja 'despesa', pinta de vermelho, senão pinta de verde. Mas você pode escolher a cor que quiser.

No exemplo que citei, fiz uma condição usando uma *string* pra facilitar, mas recomendo usar um campo *integer* 0 para despesa e 1 para receita.

Answer (score 1):

no `OnDrawColumnCell` do `DBGrid`:

```
    if (DBRadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0) then  
      DBGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed  
    else  
      DBGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;


DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
```

Comment: Comecei a participar hoje da comunidade, ainda não domino a usabilidade do site incluindo formatação, mas obrigado pela bronca....

Comment: Não encare como uma bronca, e desculpe se passei essa impressão. Mas a formatação aqui no *SOpt* é fundamental... tem gente que da bronca feia.. Abraço e espero poder lhe ajudar em outras ocasiões.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado, estamos juntos....

Answer (score 0):

No evento `onDrawColumnCell` do `DBGrid` você deve incluir o código:

```
if DBRadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0 then
begin
  DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  DBGrid1.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field, State);
end
else
begin
  DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  DBGrid1.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field, State);
end;
```

Caso você queira ao invés de trocar a cor da linha, apenas trocar a cor da fonte, altere a linha:

```
DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
```

por

```
DBGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
```

ou ainda combine as duas linhas, alterando tanto o fundo como a fonte.